# Storing the values into database using php forms

Tags: php, mysql, forms, mysqli

Final Edit:
Thank you everyone for the help. I have been trying to write all the code related to connection in index.php rather than submit.php. It is resolved now.

---

Edit:

I have updated the code based on your feedback.
I am able to get the values to the database now but the thing is it is showing only empty results. here is the updated code.

```
 <form action="submit.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name" class ="col-lg-2 control-label" > Name</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-7">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id ="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your Name" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                </div>
             <div class="col-lg-1">

             </div>
                <div class="form-horizontal" >

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email" class ="col-lg-2 control-label" > Email</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-7">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id ="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                </div> <div class="col-lg-1">

             </div>
                <div class="form-horizontal" >

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="subject" class ="col-lg-2 control-label" > Subject</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-7">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id ="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Your Subject" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                </div>
             <div class="col-lg-1">

             </div>
                <div class="form-horizontal">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="message" class ="col-lg-2 control-label" > Message</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-7">
                                <textarea name="message" class="form-control" id ="message" cols="20" rows="3" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div> <!-- end form -->
                        <div class="col-lg-1">

             </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-lg-7 col-lg-offset-2">
                            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

PHP Code:

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST)) {
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db_name);//             Establishing Connection with Server
    mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8');
    if (!$conn) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error($conn));
    }
    else 
    echo "connected successfully";

//Escaping string, not 100% safe, also consider validating rules and sanitization
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
    $subject = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['subject']);
    $message = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['message']);
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO contact (user, email, subject, message) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$subject', '$message')");

    }
    ?>
```

[Here is the snapshot of the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCQHa.png)

---

I have a form made using HTML. I want to store the results when i submit the form in the database. The connection was successful but the data is not being stored in the database.

Basically what submit.php does is just sent the text "Successfully submited the form".

Here's my code:

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name" class ="col-lg-2 control-label" > Name</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-7">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id ="name" placeholder="Enter your Name" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                </div>
             <div class="col-lg-1">

             </div>
                <div class="form-horizontal" >

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email" class ="col-lg-2 control-label" > Email</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-7">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id ="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                </div> <div class="col-lg-1">

             </div>
                <div class="form-horizontal" >

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="subject" class ="col-lg-2 control-label" > Subject</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-7">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id ="subject" placeholder="Your Subject" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                </div>
             <div class="col-lg-1">

             </div>
                <div class="form-horizontal">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="message" class ="col-lg-2 control-label" > Message</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-7">
                                <textarea name="message" class="form-control" id ="message" cols="20" rows="3" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div> <!-- end form -->
                        <div class="col-lg-1">

             </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-lg-7 col-lg-offset-2">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

PHP code:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db_name);//         Establishing Connection with Server
mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8');
if (!$conn) {
die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error($conn));
}
else 
    echo "connected successfully";

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

//Escaping string, not 100% safe, also consider validating rules and sanitization
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
$subject = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['subject']);
$message = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['message']);
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO contact (user, email, subject, message) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$subject', '$message');");
if ($result) {
$message="successfully sent the query!!";
}
else
{$message="try again!!";}
}
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of your input fields have a `name=""` attribute, including the button. So none of these fields will be sent in the $_POST array.

Add a `name=""` attribute like this to all the fields you want sent to PHP

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="name" class ="col-lg-2 control-label" > Name</label>
       <div class="col-lg-7">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id ="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your Name" required>
       </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">
        </div>
        <div class="form-horizontal" >
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email" class ="col-lg-2 control-label" > Email</label>
                <div class="col-lg-7">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id ="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" required>
                </div>
             </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
            <div class="form-horizontal" >
                <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="subject" class ="col-lg-2 control-label" > Subject</label>
                   <div class="col-lg-7">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id ="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Your Subject" required>
                   </div>
                </div>

         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
         <div class="form-horizontal">
             <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="message" class ="col-lg-2 control-label" > Message</label>
                 <div class="col-lg-7">
                     <textarea name="message" class="form-control" id ="message" name="message" cols="20" rows="3" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
                 </div>
             </div> <!-- end form -->
             <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                   <div class="col-lg-7 col-lg-offset-2">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn name="submit" btn-primary">Submit</button>
                   </div>
                 </div>
       </form>
```

Also in your code in `submit.php` change this so you see an actual error message if one occurs.

```
if ($result) {
    $message="successfully sent the query!!";
} else {
    $message="Insert failed : " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
echo $message;
```

Although this does assume you are actually showing the `$message` value somewhere in your code that you have not shown us.

Comment: I have added the name field but its still the same. 

What happens to the if($result) ? I am not getting any message. As soon as i click submit it goes to submit.php page

Comment: Ok also see the suggested mod for your database access error processing

Comment: Could you please take a look at the updated code ? It is returning empty fields

Comment: You did not amend the query error checking, in fact it looks like you removed it completely

Comment: Yes i did. It is getting connected to the database and whenever i submit the form, empty values are getting stored. I think there might be a small problem. I would really appreciate fi you can talk a look at it.

Comment: That if **must** return something in `$message` so what does that contain? Are you displaying that on the page?

Comment: If you take a look at my edit i have removed $message.

Comment: Yea! Well put it back and it may tell you whats wrong with the query which I assume has to be failing for some reason. You must always test the result of a query in case somethng goes wrong

Comment: I have put it back. Its the same. I am not using $message anywhere.

Comment: Well change the page so that `$message` actually gets displayed. Add the `echo` as per my last edit

Comment: My submit page has nothing other than the plain text till now.. I am adding the code to index.php. Should i have to write all the connection code in submit.php ??

Comment: Well if you can see this message `echo "connected successfully";` you shoudl also be able to see this one also `echo $message;`

Comment: I got it now. Thanks @RiggsFolly. I have to write the conditions in submit.php because as soon as form is submitted it is redirected to that page. Anyways thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :-

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db_name);//         Establishing Connection with Server
mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8');
if (!$conn) {
die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error($conn));
}
else 
    echo "connected successfully";

//Escaping string, not 100% safe, also consider validating rules and sanitization
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
$subject = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['subject']);
$message = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['message']);
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO contact (user, email, subject, message) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$subject', '$message')");

echo "INSERT INTO contact (user, email, subject, message) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$subject', '$message')";//die;

if ($result) {
$message="successfully sent the query!!";
}
else
{$message="try again!!";}
}
?>

<form action="index.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name" class ="col-lg-2 control-label" > Name</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-7">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name ="name" id ="name" placeholder="Enter your Name" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                </div>
             <div class="col-lg-1">

             </div>
                <div class="form-horizontal" >

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email" class ="col-lg-2 control-label" > Email</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-7">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id ="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                </div> <div class="col-lg-1">

             </div>
                <div class="form-horizontal" >

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="subject" class ="col-lg-2 control-label" > Subject</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-7">
                                <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" id ="subject" placeholder="Your Subject" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                </div>
             <div class="col-lg-1">

             </div>
                <div class="form-horizontal">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="message" class ="col-lg-2 control-label" > Message</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-7">
                                <textarea name="message" class="form-control" id ="message" cols="20" rows="3" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div> <!-- end form -->
                        <div class="col-lg-1">

             </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-lg-7 col-lg-offset-2">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: removed it. but of no use

Comment: I have made the changes. Take a look now. @Rahautos

Comment: No its not.. Now when i submit empty fields are being stored. Check the snapshot of the database

Comment: plz check again i do some changes in my answer @user3656329

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `name` attribute to your `button` element so that `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` will be `true`.

Please change

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

to

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

or

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

Comment: Is the code inside `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { ... }` reached? Please also add `var_dump($result);` after your `mysqli_query` to check the result of your query.

Comment: Thats because this rule applies to all input field. None of yours have a `name=""` attribute so none will be sent on the POST

Comment: I have added a name field but its still the same.

Comment: You have to specify which code is executed and which code isn't executed to make it possible for us to localize the problem.

Comment: I have some chnages @mapek. Check the edit and let me know what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must need to provide **name** attribute for each input tags and button tags for a better approach :

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name" class ="col-lg-2 control-label" > Name</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-7">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id ="name" name ="name" placeholder="Enter your Name" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                </div>
             <div class="col-lg-1">

             </div>
                <div class="form-horizontal" >

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email" class ="col-lg-2 control-label" > Email</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-7">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name ="email" id ="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                </div> <div class="col-lg-1">

             </div>
                <div class="form-horizontal" >

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="subject" class ="col-lg-2 control-label" > Subject</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-7">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name ="subject" id ="subject" placeholder="Your Subject" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                </div>
             <div class="col-lg-1">

             </div>
                <div class="form-horizontal">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="message" class ="col-lg-2 control-label" > Message</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-7">
                                <textarea name="message" class="form-control" name ="message"  id ="message" cols="20" rows="3" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div> <!-- end form -->
                        <div class="col-lg-1">

             </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-lg-7 col-lg-offset-2">
                            <button type="submit" name ="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

***Php Code for Insert data in DB :***

***`$result = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO contact (user, email, subject, message) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$email."', '".$subject."', '".$message."')");`***

Comment: I have modified the code. Please check the edit and let me know where the problem is.. It is returning empty values in the database. Check the database image too.

Comment: Have you concatenate php variables in Insert query like my query because in some cases problem occures...

Comment: tried your code too. Its the same. It is sending empty fields to the database now.